# Trigger.io PHP session expires

Tags: trigger.io

folks!

I'm trying to run an HTML app in Trigger.io. This app calls ajax to load some data from a PHP page. At this moment, I authenticate the user and start the session. After this, I have to call another PHP page. So, I check for the session started, and I found that the session is not active anymore. The second call is made right after the first one.

This happens when I try to run the app from the Trigger.io ToolKit, using iOS Simulator ( I'm using a Mac - OS X Mountain Lion ). When I test the same app in the Safari, it works perfectly: my PHP server recognizes the session started earlier, and the second page is loaded by ajax.

Is there any parameter I have to set? Or Trigger.io does not support PHP sessions?

Thank you.

Marcio

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how you are managing sessions in your PHP code? That way we have a better chance of tracking it down. Also how are you making the request in your app, are you using forge.request.ajax? Cookies should persist between requests when using Trigger, but there might be something else going on here.

Comment: @Connorhd , please, see my "answer" below. I describe details about the problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `forge.request.ajax(params)` to make ajax requests, this is because of cross domain restrictions, as Forge apps are loaded as `file://` urls on iOS.

`forge.ajax.request` takes a similar input to jQuery's $.ajax so you can easily switch between them if you want to use the same code on a website as well as in your Forge app.

More documentation is available in our docs: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/request.html#ajax

Answer (score 0):

@Connorhd , thank you so much for helping!

First of all, I do an ajax request to "app_authUser.php" to authenticate user. Then, if Ok, I do another ajax request to "app_loadFeed.php" to load data from server.

In the first ajax request, I pass, in the post parameters, the user data ( login and password ) to authenticate the user on database. The first command I call on the php file "app_authUser.php" is "session_start()", as follow:

CODE FOR "app_authUser.php" ON THE SERVER SIDE:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Just for test;
    $idSession = session_id(); 
    echo $idSession;

    /*
     Test user authenticate. If ok, then I assign idUser to $_SESSION['idUser'] variable.
    */

    if( $loginOk == true ){
        $_SESSION[ 'idUser' ] = $User->idUser;
    }
?>
```

In the code above, the user is authenticated and $_SESSION['idUser'] is correctly initiated. In the second ajax request, I test if the variable $_SESSION[ 'idUser' ] is set. That's the point: it isn't set anymore. Again, I call "session_start()" at first:

CODE FOR "app_loadFeed.php" ON THE SERVER SIDE:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Just for test;
    $idSession = session_id(); 
    echo $idSession;

    if( isset( $_SESSION[ 'idUser' ] ) ){
        /* Load data from database to return to user.... */
        echo ...
    }
    else{
        echo '0';
    }
?>
```

The test above always return false when I call my app from Trigger.io compiler. But, when I call my app from Safari, it always returns true.

I found out that the function "session_id()" returns different values in both ajax requests when the call is made from app running on Trigger.io compiler, but the same value when app is running on Sarari:

Example:

- Requests from Trigger.io:
  First request:  echo $idSession returns "m7dbsv7qqem92os39lv5ao2ta1"
  Second request: echo $idSession returns "h49pble06n7ao9pum06kt4dph0"
- Requests from Safari:
  First request:  echo $idSession returns "2cbhin1185fm5ehvbb15k6n0b1"
  Second request: echo $idSession returns "2cbhin1185fm5ehvbb15k6n0b1"

That means the session isn't the same at the first example. Why does this happen?

I'm not using forge.request.ajax in my app. That's my ajax code, in my javascript:

```
<script>

function openAjax()
{
    try
    {
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(ee)
        {
            try
            {
                var ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(eee)
            {
                var ajax = false;
                alert("Seu navegador não suporta AJAX!")
            }
        }
    }   
    return ajax;
}

// This is the function called at second time, just after I authenticate my user and have session opened.
function loadFeed(){
    var url = CT_URLBase + 'app_loadFeed.php'; // CT_URLBase = 'http://192.168.1.100/' in my local environment.
    var parameters = '';

    var ajax = openAjax();

    ajax.open('POST', url, true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1');

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if (ajax.readyState == 4){

            if (ajax.status == 200){

                var retorno = ajax.responseText;

                if( retorno != '0' ){

                    /* Return OK!!! */

                }
                else{

                    /* Error: return is 0 (zero), that means session is not started.

                }
            }
        }
    }

    ajax.send(parameters);

}    

</script>
```

What most makes me in a misunderstanding is that the same code works perfectly in Safari, but not in Trigger.io.

By the way, I visited your website, connorhd.co.uk ! Great job! It's a great place to find "Interesting stuff"! Congratulations!

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Marcio Clume